# Proof/Reasoning to Compute Dimension of a Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra

The definition for dimension of a vector space V is the "[cardinality of a basis of  V over its base field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_(vector_space))." Why do all bases in this context have the same cardinality?

Comment: It's not the cardinality of the field but the number of basis vectors needed, hence the cardinality of the basis over the field. Plus you could have a field be the integers which wouldn't have the same cardinality as the real numbers.

Comment: Base field is in context to the intersection of fields contained in the collection.

Comment: @Triatticus I am not sure what you mean. Why would the cardinality of each basis be the same then?

Comment: Oh I see where your question is from, this is because you wouldn't expect a vector space to have different cardinality/dimension because you changed the basis

Comment: @Triatticus The integers do not form a field.

Comment: Yeah that was a poor example, I'm trying to understand which part of the article OP is talking about, I should have said $\mathbb{Q}$, I was attempting to come up with a set of differing cardinality to $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Let's just say the field is $\mathbb{R}$ to keep it simple. Would it be easier if I wrote an example of a vector space (i.e. $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ to help the question)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [dimension theorem for vector spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces) states that all bases of a given vector space will have the same cardinality.  It is a consequence of this theorem that we may properly define the "dimension" of a vector space.

One proof is given in Wikipedia.  If you're looking for a textbook reference, Insel, Friedberg, Spence proves this theorem nicely and directly.  Some texts derive this theorem using Gaussian elimination, essentially.

Comment: Do you have a source where I could see the Gaussian elimination form for it? That proof looks wicked tough.

Comment: @W.G. See the "Case 2" proof on the wiki page that I linked. The properties of the rank of a matrix can be proven directly in terms of matrices rather than using the fact that rank measures the dimension of some subspace.